# Possible to provide and xcframework without exposing its dependencies of other xcframeworks?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries, xcframework

I created an xcframework from an Xcode framework project, the framework project contains dependencies of other xcframeworks. My goal is to provide my xcframework for a client's app, hoping that the client's project can only see into my xcframework and not have access to the headers of the xcframework dependencies my project contains (since those aren't open source and not owned by me).

I've had some success where I've gotten it to the point where I just have to add my xcframework to a test app, and it all works, but the minute I delete my DerivedData folder, the test app no longer works (says it can't import the dependent private lib I'm trying to hide) if I build my xcframework project again, it works again, so seems like it needs my DerivedData folder cached. What am I missing?

*I've gone the xcframework route, but wonder if a static lib would be better for my goal of hiding the dependences and their headers contained within my project.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I really don't know what Derived Data is - just that it helps clean up projects and results in longer initial builds - but my guess is it contained these third party frameworks. Any app must have everything it needs to run. Common sense, right. So can you split out things into two frameworks? One that requires third party frameworks, one that doesn't? Beyond that, one needs to ask about **why** you've set up things like you have. It will never be accepted via normal submissions.

Comment: @dfd thanks for the response, I'm not sure if I'm setting it up the best and/or correct way. The reason for this is that the 3rd party xcframeworks my project needs are from a service we pay for, so we can view their lib, use it, review there headers, once we wrap those up in our xcframework, the client can app uses it, the client app is being built by a software house that can not be allowed to view the dependent xcframeworks

Comment: Did you use `@_implementationOnly import` ?

Comment: @Yonat, no I haven't looking into that now.

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-privatize-dependencies-in-swift-package-manager/33523